# How to set color on a DetailsView based on a value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

Using ASP.NET 4 with C#.

I have a `DetailsView` which I populate using code-behind in C#, basically binding a `DataTable` from SQL Server to the `DetailsView`. I would like to change the color of values in the details view so that positive values are green, zeroes are default and negative values Red. What's the best way to do this?

**UPDATE**

@Jay I've tried this code:

```
private System.Drawing.Color GetColorValue(decimal value)
{
    if (value > 0)
        return System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    else if (value < 0)
        return System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    return System.Drawing.Color.White;
}

protected void dtlOpenTrade_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (BoundField field in dtlOpenTrade.Fields)
    {
        field.ItemStyle.BackColor = GetColorValue((decimal)dtlOpenTrade.DataItem.GetType().GetProperty(field.DataField).GetValue(dtlOpenTrade.DataItem, null));
    }
}
```

But I get this error: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Any ideas?

**UPDATE2**

I've solved it with this code, make sense?

```
void RenderDetailsViewColour(DetailsView dtl)
{
    foreach (DetailsViewRow row in dtl.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Text != "TradeId")
        {
            row.Cells[1].BackColor = GetColorValue(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Text));
        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be 'the best way' but you can handle the `DataBound` event on the details view, grab a reference to each of the controls contained, then change their color based on value.

This is a rough example:

Your business object:

```
public class BusinessObject
{
    public decimal ValueOne { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueTwo { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueThree { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueFour { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueFive { get; set; }
}
```

The DetailsView markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="false">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ValueOne" HeaderText="One" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ValueTwo" HeaderText="Two" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ValueThree" HeaderText="Three" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ValueFour" HeaderText="Four" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ValueFive" HeaderText="Five" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Wire up the event and bind data in code-behind:

```
        this.DetailsView.DataBound += new EventHandler(DetailsView_DataBound);
        this.DetailsView.DataSource = new BusinessObject[] { myBusinessObject };
        this.DetailsView.DataBind();
```

Write a routine to take a value and return colors. This can be expanded to return a couple of values such as background, forcolor, etc...

```
    System.Drawing.Color GetColorValue(decimal value)
    {
        if (value > 0)
        {
            return System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        else if (value < 0)
        {
            return System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        return System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
```

Finally the event handler

```
void DetailsView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (BoundField field in this.DetailsView.Fields)
    {
        field.ItemStyle.BackColor = GetColorValue((decimal)
            this.DetailsView.DataItem.GetType()
            .GetProperty(field.DataField)
            .GetValue(this.DetailsView.DataItem, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the exception coming from? I was assuming and simplying your data is decimals. The object you are binding to may be different.

Comment: I am using decimals, the error comes from `field.ItemStyle.BackColor = GetColorValue((decimal)dtlOpenTrade.DataItem.GetType().GetProperty(field.DataField).GetValue(dtlOpenTrade.DataItem, null));`

Comment: There is a lot going on in that line. Need to figure out which part is null. This also assumes all the fields in your `DetailsView` are `BoundField`s

Comment: @Jay: Check my UPDATE 2. Make sense?

Comment: That will work too. You just have to make sure your method gets called every time the DetailsView is databound.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts were the same as Jay's.

Markup:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount Paid" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AmountPaid") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code:

```
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label objLabel = (Label)DetailsView1.FindControl("Label1");
    if (objLabel != null)
    {
        Decimal decValue = Convert.ToDecimal(objLabel.Text);
        if (decValue > 0)
        {
            objLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        else if (decValue < 0)
        {
            objLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This way will work as well, you just have to make sure each field you want styled is accounted for in your method. But if you go as far as to make a template, why not just eval the style directly from markup?